# Magento 2.4.2: How to get real time current exchange rate in my custom module?

Tags: api, logic, magento2, currency

In the Magento app/code a custom module has been handling shipping for US orders so far. Since we are planning to ship orders to Canada, there is now a need to get real time exchange rates to help me recalculate subtotal(selling price in US) in CAD. Below is the part of the code where I need to get the exchange rate between USD and CAD. Is there a way to accomplish this?

```
if ($request->getDestCountryId() == "CA") {
    $this->_logger->info("Country ID: " . $request->getDestCountryId());
    $fedex_results = $this->carrierFedex->collectRates($request);
    // $this->_logger->info("Fedex Rate " . $fedex_rate);
    // 1. Get the array of method objects from $fedex_results object
    // 2. Loop through the array of method objects to set carrier.
    // 3. Set carrier to custom shipping. 
    // 4. Add brokerage to the shipping cost based on the table canada_brokerage_fees.

    // \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $methods
    $methods = $fedex_results->getAllRates();
    foreach ($methods as $method) {
        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        // Set new price with brokerage added to the shipping cost.
        // Get subtotal from the $request object.
        // Recalculate subtotal in CAD
        // Create table canada_brokerage_fee in Magento DB
        // Compute brokerage.
        $subtotal = $request->getOrderSubtotal();
        //recalculate $subtotal in CAD.
        **// Code to get the exchange rate...**

        $brokerage = 0;
        //$method->setPrice($method->getPrice+$brokerage);
    }

    return $fedex_results;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this extension. I found it quite useful in your case https://marketplace.magento.com/sanjay-module-custom-currency-updater.html